# Show that $x$ must be a global maximum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{+} $ be a $C^1$ function that satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$. Suppose there is only a single point $x\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ en donde $f'(x)=0$. Show that $x$ must be a global maximun of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

My try:

We know for some $n>0$, $f(x)<0.5$ for $x>n$.

Now focus on $f$ restricted to closed and bounded (hence compact) interval $[0,n]$.

A continuous function on a compact set takes a maximum so some $x^*\in[0,n]$ will exists with $f(x^*)=\max(\{f(x)\mid x\in[0,n]\}$.

My question is, how I use $f'(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $y$ such that $f(y)\geq f(x), y\neq x$. If $y<x$, there exists a point $z\in[0,y]$ such that $f(z)=f(x)$ since $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous.
This implies that there exists a point $c\in (z,x)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. (Rolle)

Suppose that $y>x$, there exists a point $z_1>y$ such that $f(z_1)<f(x)$ since $lim_\infty f=0$. This implies there exists a point $z\in [y,z_1]$ with $f(z)=f(x)$. Rolle implies the existence of a point $c\in (x,z)$ with $f'(c)=0$.